# Can I create object of child class using method from parent class

Tags: php

So I have this parent class:

```
    class Table {

    protected static $table_name;
    protected static $tbl_columns=array();

    public static function instance($row_from_db){
        $object=new self;
        foreach (self::$tbl_columns as $key=>$property){
            $object->$property =    $row_from_db[$property];
        }
        return $object;
    }
 }
```

When I call "instance" method in some child class of class Table it generates the object of class Table not the object of child class.

Is there some way to do that with this code? Or any advice on how you would solve it? Thanks

Comment: ...Isn't this what constructors are for? Or am I missing something because I don't know much PHP?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: They are using this statically.

Comment: @AbraCadaver ...Coming from a Java/C# background, that makes no sense, so I'm gonna nod and pretend I get it and not ask a question in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP 5.3.0 use [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php):

```
$object = new static;
foreach (static::$tbl_columns as $key=>$property){
```

This also works:

```
$class = get_called_class();
$object = new $class;
foreach ($class::$tbl_columns as $key=>$property){
```